# I booked through Expedia 4 days ago and the charge still isn’t in my bank account! Any advice?

Tags: usa, air-travel

I am a college student flying back home for the first time in nearly 2 years for Christmas. I have a part-time job and only a small amount of disposable income. My bills are paid but I don’t want my account to be charged and not be able to pay the money and then have to cancel my flight because it’s too much money later on. I can’t contact my bank because it’s a weekend, so I would have to make all of the phone calls come Monday. Any advice?

Comment: What did Expedia say when you contacted them? Have you got a booking confirmation with a PNR?

Comment: How did you pay? Debit card, credit card, other mode of payment? When you check your bookings in your account on Expedia, does the trip show up? Does it show up as confirmed and paid? Did you receive a booking confirmation?

Comment: Most flights will be taken out of the account offered within a few days but we recently had a question where the charge did come through (or at least they tried to get the money) after 4 months. Better keep the money in your account till they take it.

Comment: If this is money you've already budgeted towards the flight and is in the account why wouldn't you be able to afford it later?

Answer (score 4):

Just pretend it's already been deducted...dont go out and spend more just because you havent been charged yet. Understand that if you do that, when the charge finally comes in your account will go into negative. Then, as a starving college student, you will sink deeper into financial peril after you pay fees to your bank and United for not having the money there when they finally come for it. Expensive lesson to learn as a young adult...